# News of the world

Tags: grid-deduction, anagram, nonogram

Here's a quick little puzzle to keep busy.

[image]

Comment: I think the single 10 in the downward column should be an 11

Comment: I agree with @BeastlyGerbil :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I actually fixed that in my Excel sheet but forgot to make a new screen capture of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the solved nonogram (grey squares indicate gaps):

> [image]
>  <sub>*Note that this depends on assuming column 10's encoding should actually be '11' instead of '10'. Without assuming this as an error, the puzzle would be unsolvable...*</sub>

What does this produce?

> A series of letters encoded in [semaphore](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Semaphore_Signals_A-Z.jpg), which spell **RACOON**.

How does this relate to the title?

> Seeing as the animal would actually be spelled 'RACCOON' (double C), this is not the intended answer as it stands. In actual fact, this word is intended to be an anagram of another word more prevalent in the news right now: **CORONA**(virus).

Comment: Wow, that *was* quick! Spot on as usual.

Comment: As a fan of RE... OwO